# Bug with Zend File field - file name doesn't re-populate in zend form

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I'm noticing what I think is a bug with Zend_Form_Element_File. Can others please test it and tell me if they get the same result. On a failed form, all fields re-populate except the value of Element_File.

My form has 2 text fields and 1 file field and all are required.

```
$name = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('name');
$name->setLabel('Name');
$name->setRequired(true);
$this->addElement($name);

$name2 = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('name2');
$name2->setLabel('Name2');
$name2->setRequired(true);
$this->addElement($name2);

$file = new Zend_Form_Element_File('file');
$file->setLabel('Test file')
     ->setDestination(APPLICATION_PATH);
$file->setRequired(true);
$this->addElement($file);

$submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');       
$submit->setLabel('Submit')
$this->addElement($submit);
```

Normally when a form fails, it automatically populates whatever fields were filled out, but it doesn't work for the file field, and I have to manually select the file again, in addition to correcting the other fields that need correcting.

First of all, could others confirm this?

I think the problem is related to the markup of the file field. I'm seeing that the first `<input>` is the file size and then the file itself comes in the second `<input>`.

```
<dd>
<input type="hidden" id="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="67108864" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE">
<input type="file" id="file" name="file">
</dd>
```

and when a valid form is submitted, the post data shows only the first `<input>` of the file field which is the size `[MAX_FILE_SIZE] => 67108864` and not the file itself.

```
Array ( 
   [name] => test 
   [MAX_FILE_SIZE] => 67108864
)
```

When the form is valid, the upload works fine so I know nothing's wrong with the file field itself, but in the case of a failed form (correct file field but one of the other fields is invalid), the file field is the only field that doesn't get re-populated when the form renders. So is this a bug? It's annoying to have to re-add the file when there was nothing wrong with it. Is there a workaround that someone can think of. I tried doing a manual populate in case of invalid form, hoping that it would force the file field to populate, something like this, but it also did not work.

```
   if(//valid form){
      //process the form
   } else {
       $form->populate($this->_request->getPost());     
   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a bug with `Zend_Form`.  It's a limitation HTMLs file upload input element. Browsers will ignore and value set on a file input for security reasons.  If this limitation wasn't in place, malicious websites could pre-populate the file input with things like

```
/etc/password
c:\Windows\Location\Of\Sensative\File.txt
```

and then auto post the contents of your hard drive to any server.

One common work around is to use something like the [ajax form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) for jQuery to post the upload via an ajax request.  When it fails, the file upload stays selected, as there's no page refresh.

Answer (score 1):

it is no a bug. Some Zend_Form elements has not repopulate functionality. This made for some specific elements (password, file, ...). I think that it is correct.